# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to write php to connect data from myqsl (i use free host 000webhost.com)

file connect:

```
<?php

    $connect = mysqli_connect("files.000webhost.com:21", "nguyendang", "password", "foodcourt_db") or die ("could not connect to sever " . mysqli_connect_error()) ;
    mysqli_query($connect, "SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 

?>
```

[I had these errors when i ran](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUU2t.png)

Comment: Can you add the relevant code ( redact passwords etc ) and show how it is being used. Are you using `stored procedures` ?

Comment: is it really using port 21? That is typically reserved for FTP

Comment: when i try with no port, it shows this : "Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /storage/ssd4/959/14261959/public_html/db_conn.php on line 2
could not connect to severConnection refused"

Comment: i dont know what is the typical port

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect to MySQL database in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31376095/how-to-connect-to-mysql-database-in-php)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053613/apache-mysql-packets-out-of-order-on-3306

Comment: My guess is that you've mixed up the mysql server with the ftp server. Not only are you using port 21, which usually is used for FTP (Mysql defaults to 3306). Then the URL starts with `files.` which is an odd subdomain for a SQL server. I would recommend that you talk to the hosting company and ask what host, database and credentials you should use to connect to the database. You should also ask if they support remote connections or if you need to use `localhost` and run the code on their servers.

Comment: i think i see my problem, tks guys

Answer (score 0):

Try hostname with **localhost**. And also check the MySQL server is currently running.
This may happen in hosting for less duration due to overload of MySQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this connection:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database_name");
//check connection
if($link === false) {
die("ERROR could not connect. " .mysqli_connect_error());
}
```