# How do i connect to a databse to a remote server (which runs phpmyadmin) which is not owned by me

Tags: php, database, web, phpmyadmin

So my dad has a really old website and now it's my turn to redesign everything basically.
I asked the hosting company for access and they gave me login data (name, user and pwd)
My plan is to build a database-driven website using PHP as backend and javascript, HTML, CSS on the frontend site. So I was wondering how can I connect to that database, first of all, to test it using localhost and second how do I do this on a mac? When I go to the link the hosting company gave me, there's a PHPMyAdmin login where I can login with the credentials they gave me but I don't know how to connect

Comment: Use MySQL Workbench

Comment: PHPMyAdmin *is not* a database. It is a web interface for your MySQL database.
What you need are the credentials to login to MySQL (likely the same) and a URL for the actual database which you may find in the settings for PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and for host i guess it‘s localhost Right?

Comment: Since you're accessing it remotely it will not be localhost.

Comment: @JayBlanchard ah i understand now everything seems a bit clearer, so i guess i don’t Need amorpheren interface like mysql workbench since phpmyadmin is one  And as for the login i use localhost for the Host Right? Even if i Switch to Production?

Comment: If you're building the web site on another host you cannot use localhost, you will need the URL for the database. You may have to request that information from the current host and make sure they allow remote connections.

Comment: Ok i understand, Thank you i‘m Going to try it out rn

Comment: @OTRAY: It is a very good question. 
Unfortunately I think it is not realy solvable. You are asking for the database to connect to and that depends on your infrastructure. Your admins set up a database on some machine and I cannot guess the machine. Can I?
Maybe that helps for the general coding in PHP:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31376095/how-to-connect-to-mysql-database-in-php