# How to store AES key in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, aes

I'm doing AES encryption. So after I encrypt using AES, I store the encryption key and iv to MySQL so I can select to decrypt later. But when I insert the key and iv to the database, the value becomes weird and later when I use the key and iv from the database to decrypt, it just gives me a blank.

Code to encrypt and push to database

```
public function createAdmin($Firstname,$Lastname,$NRIC,$Gender,$Hospital,$phone,$address,$email,$password){ 
        
        $TableName="hospitaladmin"; 
        //Define cipher 
        $cipher = "aes-256-cbc"; 

        //Generate a 256-bit encryption key 
        $encryption_key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32); 

        // Generate an initialization vector 
        $iv_size = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher); 
        $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($iv_size); 

        //Data to encrypt 
        $encrypted_data_NRIC = openssl_encrypt($NRIC, $cipher, $encryption_key, 0, $iv);
        $encrypted_data_pw = openssl_encrypt($password, $cipher, $encryption_key, 0, $iv); 

        //$decrypted_data = openssl_decrypt($encrypted_data, $cipher, $encryption_key, 0, $iv); 


        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->conn, "INSERT INTO $TableName ( Firstname, Lastname, NRIC, Gender, Hospital, phone, address, email, password)
        VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"sssssisss", $Firstname,$Lastname,$encrypted_data_NRIC,$Gender,$Hospital,$phone,$address,$email,$encrypted_data_pw);
        // set parameters and execute   
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        

        $SQL = "SELECT HospitalAdminID FROM $TableName WHERE NRIC = '" . $encrypted_data_NRIC . "' ";
        $result = @mysqli_query($this->conn, $SQL);

        $getInfo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $userID = $getInfo['HospitalAdminID'];

        $usertype = "HospitalAdmin";

        $stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($this->conn, "INSERT INTO encryptiontable ( UserType, UserID, EncryptionKey, iv)
        VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2,"siss", $usertype,$userID,$encryption_key,$iv);
        // set parameters and execute   
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt2);
```

Code to decrypt and show in on table

```
public function displayAllHospitalAdmin() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM hospitaladmin";
        $result = @mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $fullname = $row["Firstname"] . " " . $row["Lastname"];
            $Encryptionsql = "SELECT * FROM encryptiontable where UserID = '" . $row['HospitalAdminID'] . "' and UserType = 'HospitalAdmin' ";
            $Encryptresult = @mysqli_query($this->conn, $Encryptionsql);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($Encryptresult)==0){
                $NRIC = $row["NRIC"];
            }
            else{
                $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Encryptresult);
                echo '<script language="javascript">';
                //echo 'alert("'. $data["UserType"]. ', test")';
                echo '</script>';
                $cipher = "aes-256-cbc";
                $NRIC = openssl_decrypt($row["NRIC"], $cipher, $data['EncryptionKey'], 0, $data['iv']); 
            }
            echo "<td>" . $NRIC . "</td>" ;
            }
         }
```

The encryption key value in MySQL

```
~Y?w????h???????\]8e1,EAU
```

The datatype I use for storing the key is **VARCHAR(255)**

Comment: What data type do you use for the field that stores the encryption key?

Comment: The datatype i use is Varchar(255)

Comment: What is the column collation and what is the connection charset?

Comment: Collation is utf8mb4_general_ci. How do i check for the connection charset?

Comment: What did you set in `set_charset()` method when opening the connection?

Comment: *The datatype I use for storing the key is VARCHAR(255)* This is wrong for encrypted value which is binary string. Use VARBINARY datatype. Alternatively you may convert the value to HEX string (twice length) and back - in this case VARCHAR is suitable.

Comment: See this post if you are using mysqli https://stackoverflow.com/a/60021264/1839439 but I agree that this should not have been stored as a text but as a binary data.

Comment: @Dharman, i didn't set any set_charset() when i opening the connection.

Comment: @Akina, Which method will u recommend? which one is safer?

Comment: Ok thanks for all the reply i will go check it out

Comment: Converting to HEX textual representation is, of course, more safe (0-9A-F are not charset/collation-dependent and are not influenced by another possible convertions) - but it needs in twice storage size, as I have said above.

Comment: Considering the length of the key, storage size is probably not going to be an issue. Storing encryption keys in plain text in a table will be.

Comment: Keys and IVs are binary data. You can stored them in `BLOB` columns directly, or in `VARCHAR` columns if you "render" them into strings first using HEXA (x2 storage) or BASE64 (x1.33 storage) encoding.